# SSAS Calculated Measure for Last YTD aggregates entire year

Tags: sql-server, mdx, olap, ssas-2012

I have the basic Adventureworks Date Dimension called Dates with a Hierarchy called -CalendarYear.  I need to create Members that will give me the a LYFinal aggregation and a LYTD aggregation.  I've tried the sum(YTD with parallelperiod to no Avail.  In fact Sum(YTD and sum( yield the same results, an aggregation containing the entire previous year.  Here is the code.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[LYTD_Amount]
 AS SUM(YTD(ParallelPeriod([Dates].[-CalendarYear].[Year]
    , 1
    , [Dates].[-CalendarYear].CurrentMember))
    , [Measures].[Actual Detailed Amount] 
), 
FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0;-$#,##0", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Amount LY Final]
 AS SUM(ParallelPeriod([Dates].[-CalendarYear].[Year]
    , 1
    , [Dates].[-CalendarYear].CurrentMember)
    , [Measures].[Actual Detailed Amount] 
), 
FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0;-$#,##0", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP =
```

My Date dimension is a time type.  Year and Date are set to Years and Days.

If I write some MDX from a query window the YTD function still does not limit to the day one year ago for the LYTD value.  Here is my MDX code ( It is not my intent to use MDX to query the data.  The user will simply filter for 2016 data, grab this measure and it should provide the 2015 values for previous entire year and previous YTD)

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Current YTD] AS
SUM(YTD([Dates].[-CalendarYear].CurrentMember), [Measures].[Actual Detailed Amount])
MEMBER [Measures].[Last YTD] AS 
SUM(YTD(ParallelPeriod([Dates].[-CalendarYear].[Year]
, 1
, [Dates].[-CalendarYear].CurrentMember))
, [Measures].[Actual Detailed Amount] 
)
SELECT {[Measures].[Current YTD]
, [Measures].[Last YTD]
} ON 0
FROM [Event_Lawson_Dev]
WHERE ([Dates].[-CalendarYear].[Date].&[2016-06-15T00:00:00])
;

--Hardcoded dates to force the YTD
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Current YTD] AS
SUM({[Dates].[-CalendarYear].[Date].&[2016-01-01T00:00:00]:[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[2016-06-15T00:00:00]}
, [Measures].[Actual Detailed Amount])
MEMBER [Measures].[Last YTD] AS 
SUM( {[Dates].[-CalendarYear].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]:[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-06-15T00:00:00]} 
, [Measures].[Actual Detailed Amount] 
)
SELECT {[Measures].[Current YTD]
, [Measures].[Last YTD]
} ON 0
FROM [Event_Lawson_Dev]
;
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that is the user ranges on the Date instead of the Year. The YTD function actually works.  This poses two problems though.  1. The user will  only range on the Year and the function needs to know that YTD goes only to Now() somehow.  2. The LY Final figure then summed up only the values on that date for a year ago. How to get the whole year once we figure out how to get the YTD working.

Comment: do you have future dates in your cube?